# Number cells for UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I am trying number cell from 0-X for a uitableview. Currently I am using a label to do it and I just want the labels text to be 0,1,2,3,4,...X.

```
//label for the cell
    let cellFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 32)
    var cellLabel = UILabel(frame: cellFrame)
    cellLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    cellLabel.font = UIFont.MDFont.regularFourteen
    cellLabel.text = ("\(indexPath.row)")
```

I have tried this approach and it just does 0,1,2,3,4 but when I scroll it prints 0,1,2,3,4 on top of the other numbers as well.

This is the whole code for the function

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

    if cell == null {
        //label for the cell
        let cellFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 32)
        var cellLabel = UILabel(frame: cellFrame)
        cellLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        cellLabel.font = UIFont.MDFont.regularFourteen
        cellLabel.text = ("\(indexPath.row)")
        cell.contentView.addSubview(cellLabel)
    }


    //print("Table data is \(tableData[5])")
    return cell
}
```

Comment: you may be reload the cell data?

Comment: You should run code for cellLabel.text not in the block which initializes cell. I'm guessing you are doing it only if cell==null.

Comment: cells are reused, so when that happens you probably add a second label...

Comment: Please show us how your whole cellForRow function looks like.

Comment: change dequeReusableCell... to init. dont reuse the cell.

Comment: Write UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]init];

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

    if let cellLabel = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(10) as? UILabel {
        cellLabel.text = ("\(indexPath.row)")
    }
    else {
        let cellLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 32))
        cellLabel.tag = 10
        cellLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        cellLabel.font = UIFont.MDFont.regularFourteen
        cellLabel.text = ("\(indexPath.row)")
        cell.contentView.addSubview(cellLabel)
    }

    //print("Table data is \(tableData[5])")
    return cell
}
```

When you compare variables you have to use nil.

Also in your case if the cell was nil, you should have created one. Because as you have it you try to add a label to a cell that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue related reusable cell. kindly try below code. may it help you.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

    if cell == null {
        //label for the cell
        let cellFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 32)
        var cellLabel = UILabel(frame: cellFrame)
        cellLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        cellLabel.font = UIFont.MDFont.regularFourteen
        cellLabel.text = ("\(indexPath.row)")
        cell.contentView.addSubview(cellLabel)
    }
    else {
        for obj : AnyObject in cell.contentView.subviews {
        if let label = obj as? UILabel {
            label.text = ("\(indexPath.row)")
        }
    } 
    }


    //print("Table data is \(tableData[5])")
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See, when your table is loaded, your cells are nil for  the visible region of screen... Here, its 4 cells, so your cell is nil condition will be satisfied for all 4 cells and you will get 4 cells having 0,1,2,3 text. But now when you scroll down, your cell will be reused and it wont go inside the condition so, it will show the old value that you've added in one of the above cells and hence will get wrong values.. You can use a simple approach: 
Give tag (say, 1234) to your label when you allocate it when your cell is nil and access it outside the if condition, using that tag get that label and set text to it outside the if condition.. So, it will be called everytime and you will get 0,1,2,3,....X as you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

Replace cellForRowAtIndexPath with this.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

var cell : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 44))

let cellLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 32))
cellLabel.tag = 10
cellLabel.textAlignment = .Center
cellLabel.text = ("\(indexPath.row)")
cell.addSubview(cellLabel)

return cell
}
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is getting your row index using indexPath.row.  Just create a local variable with the index thats added to the cell in the function cellForRowAtIndexPath() before the cell is returned. Then just reset the cellIndex=0 before calling reloadData(). I believe that would work

i.e

```
var cellIndex = 0

func ..cellForRowAtIndexPath ...()
{
//set the index to the cell label. 
cell.label = cellIndex++
return cell
}
```

Comment: The same thing happened. I had 0,1,2,3,4 that worked just great but after that it was 5 with 0 on top of it.

Comment: No. This is not a good suggestion. Use indexPath.row to get the index of the cell right.